# problem with my Navigation Controller code in swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have 5 view controllers for my 5 tab bar items in my app now. Each view controller has the same styling and just have a different title.

Here is the function I'm using in all these view controllers individually and calling the function in viewDidLoad()

```
 private func setupNavBar() {
    let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
    navBar?.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.title = "Library"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
    navBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 10, green: 10, blue: 10)
    navBar?.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBar?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    navBar?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navBar?.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

I don't want to do this in every VC. Instead I want to call a function like the following

```
setupNavBar(with largeTitles: Bool, has title: String)
```

I tried to create a new file Functions.swift and added the code as a function but I'm getting the errors as navigationContoller, navigationBar, navigationItem as undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an extension on the `UIViewController` like this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    public func setupNavBar(with largeTitles: Bool, has title: String) {
        let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
        navBar?.prefersLargeTitles = largeTitles
        navigationItem.title = title
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
        navBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 10/255, blue: 10/255, alpha: 1)
        navBar?.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navBar?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

        navBar?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navBar?.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

You can then just call it like this from inside any view controller:

```
self.setupNavBar(with: false, has: "Check")
```

I would tend to use a `UIViewController` extension because you are really setting up the style of the view controller itself and so could add all kinds of other setup code into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Functions: NSObject {

    public static func setupNavBar(largeTitles: Bool, title: String, viewController: UIViewController?) {
        guard let viewController = viewController else { return }
        viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = largeTitles
        viewController.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = title.capitalized
        /* ... */
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Functions.setupNavBar(largeTitles: false, title: "Library", viewController: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to subclass `NSObject` for the `Functions` class.  You could also make it a `class` function instead of `static` if you wanted.  Personally I wouldn't go this route but use an extension because you can easily end up with a `Functions` object will all kinds of random unrelated stuff in it where as extensions keep related functions nicely grouped with what they actually refer to.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code in the app delegate and the code is applied to all ViewControllers.You have to edit the properties accordingly to your requirements from the code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 224/255, blue: 227/255, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
   UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Cardo-Regular", size: 22)!]
   UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Cardo-Regular", size: 20)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
```